# Log exit code of command, similar to time command

Tags: exit, exit-status

using

```
time sleep 1
```

yields:

```
$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

is there a command I can use to print the exit code of `sleep` or whatever command I want to run?

Something likes:

```
$ log-exit-code sleep 1
```

perhaps this sufficient?

```
sleep 1 && echo "$?"
```

Comment: Nope, `sleep 1 && echo $?` would print the sleeper cell's code only when it's zero...

Comment: oh lol you're right

Comment: does anybody like the question or is it just me?

Comment: The title is merely a precursor to an excellent body of text; and by excellent I mean upvoteworthy

Comment: `sleep 1 && echo "$?" || echo "$?"`

Comment: @Jesse_b looks legit, add an answer :)

Comment: I added an answer as all the other ones so far discard the original return value, which imo is bad  (after those answers, $? is always 0 as the last thing they do is a disply, which always works. They all forgot to keep the original return value, and return it after displaying it. Therefore they just show it to an observer, but 'hide' it for the rest of the script, which can't use now "$?" to see if that important command return 0 or something else...)

Comment: Also all the solutions below can easily implement this functionality.  Kusalananda's for example would just be: `EXIT_CODE=$(tellexit command)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my testing so far this has worked:

`command && echo "$?" || echo "$?"`

Just tells it to echo the exit code if it succeeds or if it fails.

As Sato pointed out below this is essentially the same as:

`command; echo "$?"`

One thing that could make the and/or command worthwhile is something like:

`command && echo "Success! Exit Code: $?" || echo "Failure! Exit Code: $?"`

If you need your script to act on the exit code as is Olivier's concern, it is a non issue.  Your script could look something like:

```
command
case "$?" in; 
    0) echo "Command exited with: 0"
       <command if good>
       ;;
    1) echo "Command exited with: 1"
        <command if bad>
        ;;
    255) echo "Command exited with: 255"  # for ssh maybe?
         <command if 255>
         ;;
    *) echo "Command exited with: >2"
        <command for other exit code>
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Err, how's that better than just `command; echo $?` ?

Comment: I guess it's not.  `command; echo $?` is a much better answer.

Comment: uhhh this seems like it's the best option, so I chose it as the answer, if anyone disagrees, lmk

Comment: @AlexanderMills Only you knows which is the most appropriate answer to your question :-)

Comment: I am open to persuasion lol

Comment: I actually like Kusalananda/thrig's answers better.  The function is a bit more work upfront but if you want this functionality with more than one command it will save you time in the long run.

Comment: I dislike this : this changes the exit code after `command ; echo $?` because `echo $?` always succeeds and therefore after it, the new value of $? is now 0. There is a way to keep the original return code even after displaying it, in case this original return code is useful later (For example: in a script, checking the return code is important before deciding how to continue). See my answer for one of several solutions (most of the answers here can be changed in the same way)

Comment: Your variable solution has a similar issue. As soon as you execute the command a second time your `returncode` variable is overwritten.  He also asked to print exit codes not save them.  To save them you could do `command; echo "command exited with: $?" >> file`

Answer (score 11):

`cmd && echo "$?"` wouldn't work since it would by necessity only print zeroes (the `echo` would only execute on successful completion of the preceding command).

Here's a short shell function for you:

```
tellexit () {
    "$@"

    local err="$?"
    printf 'exit code\t%d\n' "$err" >/dev/tty
    return "$err"
}
```

This prints the exit code of the given command in a similar manner as the `time` command does.

```
$ tellexit echo "hello world"
hello world
exit code       0

$ tellexit false
exit code       1
```

By redirecting the `printf` to `/dev/tty` in the function, we may still use `tellexit` with redirections without getting junk in our standard output or error streams:

```
$ tellexit bash -c 'echo hello; echo world >&2' >out 2>err
exit code       0
$ cat out
hello
$ cat err
world
```

By saving the exit code in a variable we are able to return it to the caller:

```
$ tellexit false || echo 'failed'
exit code       1
failed
```

---

A fancier version of the same function also prints the signal that killed the command if the exit code is greater than 128 (which means it terminated due to a signal):

```
tellexit () {
    "$@"

    local err="$?"

    if [ "$err" -gt 128 ]; then
        printf 'exit code\t%d (%s)\n' "$err" "$(kill -l "$err")" >/dev/tty
    else
        printf 'exit code\t%d\n' "$err" >/dev/tty
    fi

    return "$err"
}
```

Testing:

```
$ tellexit sh -c 'kill $$'
exit code       143 (TERM)

$ tellexit sh -c 'kill -9 $$'
Killed
exit code       137 (KILL)
```

(The `local` thing requires `ash`/`pdksh`/`bash`/`zsh`, or you can change it to `typeset` which a few other shells also understand.)

Comment: cool, how would you use tellexit, show it in action pls

Comment: @AlexanderMills See update.

Comment: It should keep the original return value and return it in the end.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Really good observation! I will amend.

Answer (score 8):

GNU [`time`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) has an option for this:

```
time -f %x sleep 1
0
```

Passes through the exit code<sup>1</sup>, unless killed by a signal<sup>2</sup>:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %x sleep 1; echo $?
0
0

$ /usr/bin/time -f %x sleep 2x; echo $?
sleep: invalid time interval ‘2x’
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
1
1

$ /usr/bin/time -f %x sleep 60s; echo $? # Press ^C before a minute elapses
0
2
```

If you want to know/handle the signal kill situation, pass `-v` and grep the stderr for the string `Command terminated by signal`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to Olivier Dulac for noting the exit code passes through.
<sup>2</sup>Also, thank you Stéphane Chazelas for pointing out kill signal exit code does not pass through.

Comment: Interresting. GNU only but interresting, as that one will (probably) keep the original return code for the rest of the code to follow (ie, it doesn't replace it with "0" as the other answers do)

Comment: It returns `0` though if the command is killed.

Comment: That might warrant a core utils bug, @StephaneChazelas?

Comment: @bishop, I agree 0  in those cases is less than ideal. But note  that, there's no general agreement as to what to report when a command is killed by a signal. Returning 128+signal number is used by a few shells. You also see things like `256+signum` or `384+signum` or even `signum/256` or `signum/256+0.5` if a core was generated (actually the status returned by `waitpid()` divided by 256). Some would give a textual representation (like`sigint` or `sigquit+core`). Still probably worth discussing on the gnu.coreutils.bugs newsgroup I agree.

Comment: (actually `time` is not part of `coreutils`, it's a [package on its own](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Time) with its own bug mailing list (bug-time@gnu.org))

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've seen all but that last one: `signum/256+0.5`. What generates _that_?

Comment: @bishop, the `system()` of traditional awks like the one still maintained by Brian Kernighan (the `k` in `awk`) or the `nawk` of Solaris, the `awk` of FreeBSD that derive from that. `awk 'BEGIN{print system("kill -s ABRT $$")}'` outputs `0.523438` when the core dump size is not limited. The behaviour of `gawk` has changed recently, with varying behaviour with `--traditional` or `--posix` (see also the return value of `close(cmd)` for more variation)

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, the exit status (as in `WEXITSTATUS(status)`) is always 0 when killed by a signal. So that `0` here is valid even if not ideal.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting history on `awk` there, good to know! Meanwhile, agreed its valid but not ideal: if one _really_ wants to know, `time -v` will emit `Command terminated by signal N`.

Answer (score 7):

Use a shell wrapper function thingy. Probably with a different name.

```
$ exito() { "$@"; echo $?; }
$ exito true
0
$ exito false
1
$ exito echo "test test"      
test test
0
$
```

(This of course will corrupt standard output, so either use the `tty` as shown by @Kusalananda or do not use it outside of interactive contexts.)

Veering off into unportable territory, some shells can report on the status of all the commands in a pipeline, not just the last one, e.g. in ZSH if you want failures reported from an entire pipeline:

```
% TRAPZERR() { print >/dev/tty $pipestatus }
% perl -e 'exit 42' | perl -e 'exit 99'
42 99
% false | perl -e 'exit 42' | perl -e 'exit 99'
1 42 99
% perl -e 'exit 42' | perl -e 'exit 99' | true
%
```

`TRAPZERR` otherwise does not fire when there is no error (on the "no news is good news" principal).

Comment: It should keep the original return value and return it in the end. Displaying (printf, echo) a simple thing (doesn't start with a '-', etc) always works, and after that display "$?" has now the value "0" as the display worked

Answer (score 2):

To be a bit more robust, send the exit status to a separate FD so it can be handled independently of stdout/stderr:

```
exit_status() {
    "$@"
    rv=$?
    echo >&3 "$rv"
    return "$rv"
}

# exit status and stdout to stdout:
> exit_status echo "hello" 3>&1
hello
0

# exit_status to stdout, stdout to /dev/null
> exit_status echo "hello" 3>&1 1>/dev/null
0
> exit_status ehco "hello" 3>&1 1>/dev/null
ehco: command not found
127

# exit_status to stdout, stdout and stderr to /dev/null
> exit_status ehco "hello" 3>&1 &>/dev/null
127
```

Note you'll need to do something with FD3 or it will say `Bad file descriptor`.

This could be configured further to provide these outputs to inputs of another program by having the other program listen on more than one FD; you could use this as a sort of early 90's Kibana :)

Comment: It should keep the original return value and return it in the end. Displaying (printf, echo) a simple thing (doesn't start with a '-', etc) always works, and after that display "$?" has now the value "0" as the display worked

Answer (score 2):

I dislike all the other answers (albeit I like a lot for their cleverness): they display the exit code but they also CHANGE IT. (the displaying part is true, hence after it the return code is 0)

Here is a modified version :

```
do_and_tell () {
   "$@"
   returncode="$?"
   printf "Execution of : \n%s\n yelded a return code of: \n%s\n" "$*" "$returncode"
   return $returncode  # the interresting addition... keeps the commands return value.
}

## usage:

prompt$ do_and_tell true
Execution of : 
true
 yelded a return code of: 
0

prompt$ echo $?
0

prompt$ do_and_tell false
Execution of : 
false
 yelded a return code of: 
1

prompt$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: actually, @bishop answer is the only other one that does keep this value, but relies on GNU's version of `time` which is not always available.

Answer (score 1):

While all the other (very interesting) answers address the *exact* question the OP asked, in practice, things are usually simpler. You just save the exit status to a variable (immediately following the command) and report or log it any way you want to. E.g. print to /dev/stderr or write/append it as a text message into a log file. And, it's also preserved for use in decision making/flow control in subsequent code.

If it's in a function:

```
function some-function () {
    local rc ## to avoid side effects
    ...
    some-command ## run any command
    rc=$?  ## save the return status in a variable
    echo "some-command returned $rc" ## optionally tell the user about it
    ...
    return $rc  ## at the end, if appropriate
}
```

If it's directly in a script:

```
some-command ## run any command
rc=$?  ## save the return status in a variable
echo "some-command returned $rc" ## optionally tell the user about it
...
exit $rc    ## at the end to tell any calling script about it, if appropriate
```

(Ducking and covering because this does not answer the *exact* question.)